# How to achieve downsampling AA/filtering in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, antialiasing, downsampling

I'm working on a game that uses pixelart and a camera that will not match the size of the pixel art one to one. To keep the pixels looking like pixels, I want to render the entire game at a higher resolution then downsample it to the actual window resolution (similar to what the GeDoSaTo mod does in Dark Souls 2) and simply use nearest filtering on the in-game textures as mag filter. How can I do this downsampling in code?

Comment: Why don't you use a shader such as Pixelate.fx in http://shazzam-tool.com/?

Comment: Nearest filtering is going to get you back to square one. If you render at a resolution ***higher*** than your display, and then sample it using a point sampling (nearest neighbor) you actually introduce a lot of high-frequency noise. This is precisely the reason mipmaps were created.

Comment: I meant, using nearest filtering on the textures in-game (as mag filter), while properly filtering the higher resolution result of rendering. I'll update the question to make that a bit clearer.

Comment: Again, you are thinking about this all wrong. What you want to do is blit the oversampled color buffer to your default framebuffer using ***linear*** filtering. Whether you do this using [`glBlitFramebuffer (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml) or drawing a textured quad is up to you, but you need linear filtering. You can implement your own filter if you want, say bicubic or lanczos, but it will be significantly slower.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. I want to use no filtering on the actual textures used on in-game objects, but the oversampled buffer would of course be used filtering on. What I need to know is how to create that buffer and how to render to that buffer rather than the default framebuffer.

Comment: You just need a [Framebuffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object). I would suggest drawing into a texture image attachment, and then stretching the resulting texture over the viewport using linear filtering when you draw into the default framebuffer. That is usually slightly better performing than `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` and you don't have to mess around with `glReadBuffer (...)`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written some pseudo-code for you that shows how to setup an FBO with dimensions:

`scale` * (`res_x` x `res_y`).

<sup>2x supersampling would use a `scale` of **2.0**.</sup>

I did some extra work to get you a texture image attachment for your color buffer, so that you can draw this using a textured quad (better performance) instead of blitting. However, since doing that would involve writing a (simple) shader, `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` was the quickest solution.

#### Code to Initialize your FBO:

```c
GLuint supersample_fbo,
       supersample_tex,
       supersample_rbo_depth;

glGenTextures (1, &supersample_tex);
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, supersample_tex);

glGenRenderbuffers (1, &supersample_rbo_depth);
glBindRenderbuffer (GL_RENDERBUFFER, supersample_rbo_depth);

// Allocate storage for your texture (scale X <res_x,res_y>)
glTexImage2D  (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, res_x * scale, res_y * scale, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

// Allocate storage for your depth buffer
glRenderBufferStorage (GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, res_x * scale, res_y * scale);

glGenFramebuffers (1, &supersample_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer (GL_FRAMEBUFFER, supersample_fbo);

// Attach your texture to the FBO: Color Attachment 0.
glFramebufferTexture2D (GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, supersample_tex, 0);

// Attach the depth buffer to the FBO.
glFramebufferRenderbuffer (GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, supersample_rbo_depth);
```

#### Code to Draw into your FBO:

```c
glBindFramebuffer (GL_FRAMEBUFFER, supersample_fbo);

// You need to modify the viewport mapping to reflect the difference in size.
// Your projection matrix can stay the same since everything is uniformly scaled.
//
glViewport        (0, 0, res_x * scale, res_y * scale);

  // DRAW
```

#### Code to Blit the FBO to the Default Framebuffer:

```c
glBindFramebuffer (GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, supersample_fbo); // READ:  Supersampled
glBindFramebuffer (GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);               // WRITE: Default

// Downsample the supersampled FBO using LINEAR interpolation
glBlitFramebuffer (0,0,res_x * scale, res_y * scale,
                   0,0,res_x,         res_y,
                   GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,
                   GL_LINEAR);
```

#### Code to resume drawing into the Default Framebuffer:

```c
// You probably want all subsequent drawing to go into the default framebuffer...
glBindFramebuffer (GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glViewport        (0,0,res_x,res_y);
```

There is a lot of missing error checking in this code, and FBOs are ***very*** error-prone, but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: One question about this, if I don't use depth testing (in the case of 2D games) should I skip everything related to the depth render buffer?

Comment: Yes, I added the depth attachment under the assumption that you needed depth testing. You mentioned Dark Souls, so I kind of got it in my head that you were doing 3D rendering ;) If you don't need a depth buffer, then remove the renderbuffer stuff.

Comment: Yes, there is an upper-bound though. You would need to query the value of `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` at run-time; neither `res_x * scale` nor `res_y * scale` can exceed this value. So the maximum amount of supersampling done this way actually depends on the initial resolution. Multisampling will give better performance (it does not have to run the fragment shader for each extra sample) and can overcome some of the size issues here, but suffers from shader/texture aliasing that supersampling does not.

Comment: For higher than 2x sampling will I have to run it through multiple passes, 2x each, or can I simply change the scale to higher? I got what looked to me like some incorrect results after raising it above 2x.

Comment: Screenshots of the problem, the 4x seems more jagged than the 2x one: 2x: http://i.imgur.com/YNvtJVE.png 4x: http://i.imgur.com/5080lYY.png

Comment: Well, there is a limitation to the number of samples linear filtering uses. It takes the 2x2 nearest pixels and computes a weighted average. You cannot change the sample window size without anisotropic filtering, and that does not apply if you blit the framebuffer. Realistically, if you are trying to reduce the appearance of jagged edges multisampling, or a custom filter kernel that takes more than 2x2 samples (this will require you to write a shader) is going to be your best bet.

Comment: The good news is you already have the code necessary to draw to a texture setup, so you can find a GLSL implementation of a 3x3 or 5x5 gaussian blur and adapt that.